# All cells have same text label in uitableviewconroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have the following function:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"stateCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *state = self.stateArray[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = state;

    return cell;
}
```

The state strings all come from this `NSArray`:

```
self.stateArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Alabama", @"Alaska", @"Arizona", @"Arkansas", @"California", @"Colorado", @"Connecticut", @"Delaware", @"Florida", @"Georgia", @"Hawaii", @"Idaho", @"Illinois", @"Indiana", @"Iowa", @"Kansas", @"Kentucky", @"Louisiana", @"Maine", @"Maryland", @"Massachusetts", @"Michigan", @"Minnesota", @"Mississippi", @"Missouri", @"Montana", @"Nebraska", @"Nevada", @"New Hampshire", @"New Jersey", @"New Mexico", @"New York", @"North Carolina", @"North Dakota", @"Ohio", @"Oklahoma", @"Oregon", @"Pennsylvania", @"Rhode Island", @"South Carolina", @"South Dakota", @"Tennessee", @"Texas", @"Utah", @"Vermont", @"Virginia", @"Washington", @"West Virginia", @"Wisconsin", @"Wyoming", nil];
```

All text labels in my `UITableViewController` show as "Alabama".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: show your tableView delegate methods.Possibly you are returning a separate section for each of your rows. `-numberOfSectionsInTableView` and `-numberOfRowsInSection` is needed.If you return a separate section for each row then you get always 0 for indexPath.row

Comment: It's better for you to debug it yourself because it's normal made by mistakes.

Comment: Oooh! Haha this has already bee resolved, huh

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally set the section function to this:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return [self.stateArray count];
}
```

It should be

```
return 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you return a cell to the UITableView Data Source, you have to check if cell is equal to nill:

```
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"stateCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

At times this function will return nill therefore you have to check if cell equals nill and if it dose you need to allocate a new cell then continue with your code:

```
if (!cell)
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier: @"stateCell"];
```

This would go **right after** creating the cell variable.

I hope this fixed the problem :)